# newcommand with two arguments, one optional

Tags: macros, editors, optional-arguments

I'm struggling with a command that doesn't do what I expect. This is my code

```
\newcommand{\expectation}[2][]{\mathrm{E}_{#1}\left[#2\right]}

\begin{document}
I get $\expectation{A}{B}$, but I expect $\mathrm{E}_{A}\left[B\right]$\\
Optional arguments, I get $\expectation{B}$, and I expect $\mathrm{E}\left[B\right]$
\end{document}
```

and this is the output
[image]

This does not make a lot of sense to me. If I skip the newcommand and directly plug in what I want, everything looks fine. But the newcommand version with both inputs does something different. What am I missing?

(Even worse: I'm sure everything worked as intended yesterday. Today it doesn't anymore)

Edit: turns out this was due to a fixed bug in Texstudio. Optional arguments have to be called with brackets

Comment: Invoke it as `\expectation[A]{B}` with square, not curly brackets around the `A`.  It is an optional argument.  Curly braces are for mandatory arguments.

Comment: Also it might be an idea to use `\ifblank` from `etoolbox` to test if the `_{#1}` is even needed.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand. My editor (TeXstudio) suggests to use curly brackets for both arguments

Comment: As it turns out, this is a known bug. Will be fixed in the next release

Comment: You also might not want to have the left right construction as it easily becomes too excessive.

Comment: No... really? A bug in a TeX editor making optional arguments be used like a mandatory one?

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `xparse` package as it keeps the default behaviors for an optional argument very manageable.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

%\ExplSyntaxOn
    \DeclareDocumentCommand{\expectation}{ O{} m }{%
        $\mathrm{E}_{#1}\left[#2\right]$%
    }
%\ExplSyntaxOff

% choose a different way of producing subscripts if you need ExplSyntax

\begin{document}
    I get \expectation[A]{B}, but I expect $\mathrm{E}_{A}\left[B\right]$\\
    Optional arguments, I get \expectation{B}, and I expect $\mathrm{E}\left[B\right]$
\end{document}
```